# Bootstrap 4 Modal Pop up window can not able to close

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I did a project on matching game. Where after all cards match and game finish, a congratulation modal pop up. But I could not able to know why it does not close, after clicking the play again button.

Here is the index.html for the modal window

```
<!--Add Bootstrap Modal Alert Window-->
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!--Modal Content-->
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!--Modal Header-->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">Congratulations!!!</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
            </div>

            <!--Modal Body-->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="myText"></p>
            </div>

            <!--Modal Footer-->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-default" onclick="gameStart(), $rating.removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');">Play Again!</button>
            </div> <!--modal footer-->
          </div> <!--modal-content-->
    </div> <!--modal-dialog-->
</div> <!--modal-->
```

And the javascript for Modal:

```
function gameOver(moves, score) {
$('#myText').text(`Time: ${second} Seconds, Your Move: ${moves} Moves, Total 
Score: ${score}, Well done!!!`);
$('#myModal').toggle(); 
}

if (totalCard === match) {
        rating(moves);
        let score = rating(moves).score;
        setTimeout(function () {
            gameOver(moves, score);
        },800);
    }
```

Here is the link for my matching game project:

https://codepen.io/sofianayak55/pen/wEBvvJ

Comment: nope, it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading the Bootstrap library before jQuery...

```
 <!--Add jQuery-->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Reverse the order of those 2.
;)

This created the below error in [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
>      at util.js:68
>      at util.js:10
>      at bootstrap.min.js:6
>      at bootstrap.min.js:6

I had the game done in 15 moves, 34 seconds. ;)

---

**EDIT**
Line #118 in JS was the issue. You used `$('#myModal').toggle()` (at game over, to open it).

I replaced id with `$('#myModal').modal("show");`. `data-dismiss` needs the modal to be shown using the `modal()` method. `.toggle()` is the jQuery method to display/hide an element. So since Bootstrap doesn't know the modal is shown, the `dismiss` doesn't work.

Here is your [CodePen updated](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/mGeXYo?editors=1010).

I commented a couple ressources that are local on your server... but are 404 in CodePen... So be aware if you copy/paste from it.

Comment: mmm... I tested it... Switching the order of the two lib is good... Removes the error thrown. But your issue is still there. Hold on.

Comment: but still does not close the pop up window